# ¿Crear un campo calculado a través de un campo calculado?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente duda.

He desarrollado un procedimiento almacenado que me muestra una cantidad de pares que se pueden realizar (mediante un campo calculado), donde se comprueba mediante la cantidad necesaria "cantidad" y la cantidad disponible "stock". El problema es si se rebasa el número disponible, es decir, si no se tiene la cantidad exacta de material. Para esto me gustaría crear un nuevo campo que demuestre la cantidad necesaria para poder realizar dicho procedimiento.

A continuación les muestro el procedimiento y los campos de la tabla. Gracias

PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pa_Calcular
@par int = NULL
AS
SELECT Nombre, Cantidad, Stock, Stock/Cantidad as Pares_Disponibles
FROM dbo.Inventario WHERE Stock/Cantidad < @par
GO
```

TABLA

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inventario](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Cantidad] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Stock] [float] NOT NULL,
    [CostoUnidad] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Inventario] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas a tener que hacer un case, que devuelva un cero en los casos donde tu division de < 1 y la diferencia en los otros casos.

La division que haces no se entiende bien, asi que vas a tener que agregar la cuenta al campo correspondiente, donde dice `[calculo]`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pa_Calcular
    @par int = NULL
AS
    SELECT Nombre, Cantidad, Stock, 
        CASE 
            WHEN Stock/Cantidad < 1 THEN 0
            ELSE Stock/Cantidad
        END as Pares_Disponibles
        CASE 
            WHEN Stock/Cantidad < 1 THEN [calculo]
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM dbo.Inventario WHERE Stock/Cantidad < @par

GO
```

En este caso, estamos seleccionando y mostrando un campo distinto de 0 para el caso que corresponda. y 0 cuando el caso no cumple la condicion.